# P4 get latest revision only syncs part of folder?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am trying to get files in the folder `A/` which include:

```
A
|_ A1
|_ A2
|_ _tcp
|_ _bin
```

and other subfolders under `A`. However, after running get latest revision for folder `A`, I can only have `A/A1, A/A2` in my local folder but `A/_tcp` and `A/bin` are missing. does anyone know the reason and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different reasons that a file might not get synced.  Running at least one of the following commands on a path that's not syncing should give you the answer.  I'll use the path `A/bin/...` for purposes of this example:

- `p4 opened A/bin/...` -- do you have the file open?  If so, your local file is protected from updates until you resolve, submit, or revert.
- `p4 have A/bin/...` -- does the server think you already have the file?  If so, it won't re-sync it.  Use `p4 clean` to force your workspace back into a consistent state.
- `p4 where A/bin/...` -- is the file part of your client view?  If not, you may need to update your View (or, if this is a stream workspace, your stream's Paths).
- `p4 files A/bin/...` -- does the file exist at all?  Is it deleted?  If it's deleted, maybe you want to sync an older revision?
- `p4 protects A/bin/...` -- do you have access to the file?  If not, talk to your admin.

Comment: ...and if you haven't, turn on logging. It will provide you with a clue as to which one of these circumstances fits yoru case.